# Draw Coordinates problem in QGIS map composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm new to QGIS and am having trouble with the Draw Coordinates feature in Map Composer. Extensive Googling has not provided any solutions. With reference to the attached image, the coordinates around the page perimeter vary between UTM and degrees, which I find odd. I'm suspecting something to do with the project CRS.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What do you want it to be?

Comment: @Vesanto I'd like UTM. You can see in the top left of image that it is in UTM, but then changes to degrees, which I don't want. Either way, I find it odd that it is showing two formats at the same time. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you set the CRS to the correct UTM zone?

Comment: @Vesanto unfortunately, it is set to the correct UTM zone already.

Comment: Based on the picture it is set to: EPSG:28350 http://epsg.io/28350 What is your data in?

Comment: @Vesanto I've tried setting all layers to the same CRS and have tried a few different CRS options ranging from Mercator to WGS84, but still no luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this to be a software glitch. It stopped happening after updating QGIS.